# Is it possible to have Minecraft Server World folders in a different directory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Is it possible to have a folder on my `~/minecraft_server/` folder, for example `./worlds/` in which I have my worlds saved?

A `server.properties` might look like this in that case:

```
level-name=worlds/my_world
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering myself here, I figured it out (wouldn't have needed to ask here, Trial and Error lol).

As per the German Minecraft Wiki, you can specify a path to your world folder. Using something like I mentioned above works perfectly fine. This might help to clear up confusion if you change your active world every now and then:

```
level-name=<directory>/<world_name>
```

Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties#Java_Edition_3

> The "level-name" value is used as the world name and its folder name. The player may also copy their saved game folder here, and change the name to the same as that folder's to load it instead.
> Characters such as ' (apostrophe) may need to be escaped by adding a backslash before them.

In the German wiki it is also mentioned that using a subdirectory is possible. This is left out in the English wiki.

> [..] Es ist auch möglich, hier einen Pfad anzugeben, z.B. *worlds/worldname/worlddataname* [..].

*"[..] It is possible to use a path, for example worlds/worldname/worlddataname [..]* - [German Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft-de.gamepedia.com/Server.properties#Minecraft-Servereinstellungen)